# How to translate special characters in .csv file while importing to Excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, csv

I've special characters as shown below in a `.csv` file, and while importing to Excel and to SQL server, these characters are lost. Is there a way to convert these as text?

Input:

> NAVI 7 ¼ 01/25/22,  LADR 5 ¼ 03/15/22

Output:

> NAVI 7 1/4 01/25/22,
> LADR 5 1/4 03/15/22

Comment: How are you importing it into Excel?  Using either the legacy wizard, or Power Query, the `¼` is preserved.

Comment: Is there anyway to import 1/4 as 3 characters instead of one character?

Comment: Another example, WDC 4 ¾ 02/15/26, needs to be imported as WDC 4 3/4 02/15/26?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  You **DON'T** want the special characters; you want to translate them to their equivalents. In Excel I suggest Power Query and a translation table.